# push in array of object jquery but in one object only

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

```js
var months_range = [];
var obj = {};
obj['weather'] = "winter";
$('input').each(function(index, obj) {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  obj[id] = $(this).val();
  months_range.push(
    obj
  );
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(months_range));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='jan' value='1' />

<input type='text' id='feb' value='2' />
```

I want to add only 1 object in my array which will contain all data I want to have in my array.

What I like to output is:

> [{"jan":"1","feb":"2","weather":"winter"}]

What i get is

> [{"jan":"1"},{"feb":"2"}]

Comment: You don't need `months_range` and remove obj from each param

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're shadowing, think overwriting, your outer `obj` variable with the function argument `obj` which makes the `push` operation push in a new object for each iteration. Either rename the outer variable or the function argument and it'll work, somewhat.

Furthermore you're pushing the object on to the array for each iteration which will end up giving you an `N` length array with duplicate objects, move the `push` out of the loop.

```
var months_range = [];
var monthsObj = {}; //Previously `obj`.
monthsObj['weather'] = "winter";
$('input').each(function(index, obj) {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  monthsObj[id] = $(this).val();

});
months_range.push(
  monthsObj
);
```

Comment: what should i do to get the desired ouput then? also i dont get what do you mean by shadowing

Comment: i didnt see that one coming i didnt notice i named same obj.. i need 9 mins for upvote

Answer (score 2):

Your inner `obj` parameter in the `each` is overwriting the outer `obj` variable. As you are not using it you can remove the parameter.

```js
var months_range = [];
var obj = {};
obj['weather'] = "winter";
$('input').each(function(index) {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  obj[id] = $(this).val();
  months_range.push(
    obj
  );
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(months_range));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='jan' value='1' />

<input type='text' id='feb' value='2' />
```

If you only want a single object in the array at the end, only push the data into the array after the each statement, like this:

```js
var months_range = [];
var obj = {};
obj['weather'] = "winter";
$('input').each(function(index) {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  obj[id] = $(this).val();
});

months_range.push(obj);

console.log(JSON.stringify(months_range));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='jan' value='1' />

<input type='text' id='feb' value='2' />
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `obj` from `function(index, obj)` so it looks like `function(index)`

And move `months_range.push(obj);` out of the `.each`

```js
var months_range = [];
var obj = {};
$('input').each(function(index) {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  obj[id] = $(this).val();
});
obj['weather'] = "winter";
months_range.push(
  obj
);

console.log(JSON.stringify(months_range));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='jan' value='1' />

<input type='text' id='feb' value='2' />
```

Answer (score 0):

I really did not understand your question but seems that gives the result you want.

```js
var obj = {};
obj["weather"] = "winter";

[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName("input"), function(e){
  obj[e.id] = e.value;
});

console.log(obj);
```

```html
<input type='text' id='jan' value='1' />

<input type='text' id='feb' value='2' />
```